# Linear regression results interpretation check

Tags: regression, time-series, anova

I have below results of my linear regression and my interpretation. Is it correct?

Regression Statistics

```
Multiple R  0.5580542474
R Square    0.311424543
Adjusted R Square   0.3108763142
Standard Error  0.01509291883
Observations    1258

ANOVA                               
            df      SS          MS          F           Significance F          
Regression  1       0.129400933 0.129400933 568.0557186 6.8943E-104
Residual    1256    0.286112026 0.000227796                 
Total   1257        0.415512959 



             Coefficients   Standard Error  t Stat      P-value    Lower 95%    Upper 95%   Lower 95.0% Upper 95.0%
Intercept   7.27719E-05     0.000425752     0.170925792 0.864309646 -0.000762491    0.000908035 -0.000762491    0.000908035
S&P 500      1.174998243    0.049299413     23.8339195  6.8943E-104 1.078279968 1.271716517  1.078279968            1.2717165
```

17

Interpretation:
calculated  P Value is less than significant level of  0.05 at 95% confidence and correlation between DAL and SP 500 is "statistically significant".   It means our correlation of 0.55805 is statistically significant, there exists a strong positive relationship between  S&P 500 daily returns and DAL daily returns.
 Results:  There is a strong positive relationship between S&P 500 daily returns and DAL daily returns . R(1256) = 0.5580, p<0.05

Comment: Because the meaning of "strong" is unclear, either avoid its use or explain what you mean by it. The phrase "less than significant level of 0.05 at 95% confidence" is hard to understand because the "0.05" and "95% confidence" appear to be expressing the same thing. The term "$R(1256)$" is unusual and undefined; one ordinarily would quote the *F* statistic with $1256$ and $1$ df.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little repetitive but basically correct.

However, it seems like both variables are time series. You want to be careful in interpreting results of a regression on time series data. This is not my specialty (I know enough to know that I don't know enough), so I am adding the time series tag so that some of the experts here can add more.